# Can you switch to a better compression algorithm for the Stack Exchange dump files?

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

This question has already been asked in one form or another but the problem still exists at least for me.

I have been working with some of the largest dump files recently e.g. `stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z` which is **9,598,631 KB** compressed.

I need to parse the data and due to the lack of proper *LZMA* stream based API in *.NET*, I am forced to first extract this to get a ~**48 GB** *XML* file which I then stream over to get the stuff I want. This results in unnecessary time and storage wasted when dealing with larger dumps.

I therefore propose using *BZIP2* which results in *slightly* less size of **9,598,624 KB** but on the more productive side, I can then use a library such as [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to decompress the file as a stream resulting in not having to extract the file first before getting my hands on the data.

Just for reference, *PPMD* consistently gives better compression (for textual data) at the cost of much slowness but then again it has the same problem of *LZMA* for not having a stream based API in *.NET* at least not a free/OSS one.

Comment: Does anybody like 7zip?

Comment: I was fairly sure it was bzip2 compressed already, just put into a .7z? See my (related, maybe duplicate) request: [Use LZMA2 or PPMd instead of bzip2 for the data dump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259540/use-lzma2-or-ppmd-instead-of-bzip2-for-the-data-dump).

Comment: No, I can confirm it's not a `BZIP2`, in fact I used the `7Zip SDK` to decompress the file as `LZMA` but it's not ideal as you would need to extract the whole file (not streamed base) and I don't want to have to do gymnastics to make `LZMA` work in _.NET_ when we can hopefully get this in a better format that can make both the Stack guys and us the users happy.

Comment: I... think you better check that. Since if the file only changes 7 KB by compressing it with a completely different algorithm... I find that hard to believe. Especially considering in a vast majority of instances, LZMA is much much better with compression than bzip2.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?! I have tested it hence this post. As explained the proposal does not focus on any gains in the compression size but the ease of decompression as a stream so that one does not have to extract the whole 68GB of data only go through it again just to take a small part of it. The size of `BZIP2` is already less (by a very small margin) than the current `LZMA` however `BZIP2` has a much better support from the API point of view at least in _.NET_.

Comment: What I'm trying to explain is there's a 99% chance bzip2 is already used for the compression. However, it is just stored in a 7z archive which has a different format than a normal bzip2 archive. And I can confirm that is the case, see [this properties screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2m8I.png) of an archive with a nice freehand circle.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is indeed `BZIP2` stored in a `7z` format which introduces additional headers at the beginning of the file. I just cannot figure out why it would decompress using `LZMA` without any errors!. All I need to do now is to ignore the headers and decompress the rest. Thanks for that. Feel free to post this as an answer and I will mark as accepted.

Comment: Wouldn't the xz format an alternative?